# Getting value of Option in Select for an Email that uses a JS Mail handler

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, html-select

I know I've posted this before, but I posted the other one when I was tired and at 2am. This one I'm able to reply quickly, and I want to get this sorted, I'll remove the other one as soon as I've posted this.

Okay, so the title may be a bit confusing, but just read this and then see if it makes more sense.

I downloaded a HTML5 website template and it came with a contact php form for the action of a form.

This is the HTML of the form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="bat/MailHandler.php">
    <div class="success">
         Contact form submitted! <strong>We have received your email and will be with you within 24 hours.</strong>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label class="topic">
                <select style="width:370px;" name="topic">
                    <option value="General">General</option>
                    <option value="Development">Development</option>
                    <option value="Graphics">Graphics Design</option>
                    <option value="Video">Video Editing</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="name">
            <input type="text" value="Your name">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="phone">
            <input type="tel" value="Telephone (Please include country code)">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="email">
            <input type="email" value="Email">
            <br>
            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="message">
            <textarea>Message</textarea>
            <br>
            <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <a class="btn btn-1" data-type="reset">Clear</a><a class="btn btn-1" data-type="submit">Send</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The MailHandler.php looks like this:

```
<?php

    // Database connect
    $db_host        = 'localhost';
    $db_user        = 'redjaxco';
    $db_pass        = 'CORRECT PASSWORD';
    $db_database            = 'redjaxco_website'; 

    $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');

    mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
    mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

    $owner_email = "contact@red-jax.com";

    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'Online Form: '. $_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }else{
        $headers = '';
    }
    if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers))
        {
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }
        else
        {
                            // ignore the SQL thing... It doesn't yet work
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (
                name,email,telephone
            ) VALUES (
                '{$_POST['name']}',
                '{$_POST['email']}',
                '{$_POST['telephone']}',
            )");

            if (!$sql)
            {
                throw new Exception('mail failed');
            }

            echo 'mail sent';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
?>
```

The MailHandler is driven by a javascript file called "forms.js".

Forms.js:

```
//forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'support@template-help.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea,select',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".topic":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:select'  },
                                                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){  
             $('#contact-form').forms({
         ownerEmail:'#'
         })
   })
```

My issue is that I want to add the select at the top of the form, which will change the subject of the message so that they can be sorted into a specific mailbox on my email account.

I have tried adding to the forms.js but with no effect, maybe I'm doing it wrong. All the code is as it was was when I downloaded the template, except the HTML form and the MailHandler. Although the MailHandler worked before I added the select and I haven't change it since then.

I'm not too great with JavaScript. HTML and PHP I'm fine with but JavaScript I'm new to. I don't know whether this is a JavaScript issue or what, I'm guessing so as that's where all the functionality is.

Thanks for any help, and don't be afraid to ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['topic']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>topic: ' . $_POST["topic"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
```

Add the above to your code. it will then fetch the select data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself with a simple JS fix.

In the HTML Form I add this:

```
<label class="topic">
    <input type="text" id="topicInput" class="hidden" /><br>
    <span class="error">*This is not an option</span>
    <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
</label>
```

and in the CSS I added this:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
```

and to the forms.js I changed the submit function from this:

```
submitFu:function(){
    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
            data:{
                topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
            },
            success: function(){
                _.showFu()
            }
        })          
}
```

To this

```
submitFu:function(){
            /* START ADDED */
    var selOption = document.getElementById('topic');
    var selVal = selOption.options[selOption.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById('topicInput').value = selVal;
            /* END ADDED */

    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
            data:{
                topic:_.getValFromLabel($('.topic',_.form)),
                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
            },
            success: function(){
                _.showFu()
            }
        })          
}
```